# Karate print variable shows #ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: karate

Sometimes, not always, when printing variables shows #ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap

```
   {
    "auth": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap",
    "cart": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap",
    "shipping": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap",
    "payment": "#ref:java.util.LinkedHashMap"
  }
```

What can I do for this?

Thanks for help

Edit: copy don't works for me

[image]

Comment: this is not duplicated question, other question don't works

Comment: it works for me. so now please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but note that the REASON for this is explained. so just a `copy` won't work. if you don't like the explanation, then you are free to use some other framework